# Can I observe an optional value in swift? If not, how might I go about attempting to observe a change?

Tags: swift, macos, swift4, key-value-observing

I'm trying to observe a change to the selection of an NSPopUpButton in Swift 4. In my view controller's viewDidLoad() I've set up the observation token to observe the selectedItem property of the NSPopUpButton

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    observation = observe(\.myPopUpButton.selectedItem) {
        objectToObserve, change in

        if change.kind == NSKeyValueObservedChange.Kind.setting {
            // code to execute goes here
        }
}
```

I set a breakpoint on the line where `observation` is set to determine that the token is being configured with the correct key path. I also set a break inside the closure to see when it is executed. When I change the selection of the NSPopUpButton, the closure does not execute.

`selectedItem` is of type, `NSMenuItem?`, so my suspicion is that I can't set an observation on an optional property. But I can't find anything in Apple's documentation that states whether or not that is the case and I'm not sure how I would go about verifying it for myself.

So I have sort of a primary question along w/ some followups:

- Can I observe an optional property in Swift 4.1?

  - If so, how can I troubleshoot this, what am I doing wrong?
  - If not, how can I go about trying to monitor the state of the NSPopUpButton?

Troubleshoots that I've already tried...

- added `@objc dynamic` to the my `myPopUpButton` declaration

Comment: Use bindings. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSPopUpButton.html

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't be able to observe an optional property so long as it exists when you start. Maybe add a test in just before the observe line to make sure everything is where you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many properties of many AppKit objects are **not** KVO-compliant. Unless the documentation specifically says the property is compliant, you should assume it's not compliant. `NSPopUpButton`'s `selectedItem` property is non-compliant.

The easiest way to be notified that the pop-up button's selected item changed is to set the button's `target` and `action`:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myPopUpButton.target = self
        myPopUpButton.action = #selector(popUpButtonDidFire(_:))
    }

    @IBAction private func popUpButtonDidFire(_ sender: Any) {
        // code to execute goes here
    }
```

Note that if you're creating the pop-up button in a storyboard or xib, you can wire it to the `popUpButtonDidFire` method by control-dragging from the pop-up button to the view controller.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! In the future, I must keep in mind that KVO-compliant properties are explicitly stated in Apple's docs

Comment: If the selected index is not KVO observable, how does the binding work? Bindings _are_ KVO.

Comment: No, bindings *are not* KVO. A binding *uses* KVO to read out the model (or controller) value, and uses KVC to set the model (or controller) value. However, the binding on the view is not necessarily KVC or KVO compliant. Consider for example that `NSPopUpButton` exposes a `contentObjects` binding, but it has no `contentObjects` property. And I don't mean it has no *documented* `contentObjects` property; I mean if you send it a `contentObjects` message, you'll get an unrecognized selector error.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments in macOS Cocoa Bindings and Swift's property observers are a very powerful way to observe values, even in prior Swift versions. An outlet is not needed.

Create a property and use the `didSet` observer

```
@objc dynamic var selectedObject : MyObject?  {
    didSet {

    }
}
```

In Interface Builder in Bindings Inspector bind `Selected Object` to the target controller `Model Key Path` > `selectedObject`.

`MyObject` is the type of the represented object of the menu item. If nothing is selected `selectedObject` is `nil`. You can bind also `Selected Index`, `Selected Tag` or `Selected Value` (but not simultaneously).